Redundant features of modern regex that should be handled by higher-level parsers
Modern regular expressions out-grow its traditional academic usage, and is now a versatile tool for text processing.
This lead to some programmer over-use regex for tasks which should've been handled by e.g. parsers based on context-free grammars. For example, there were lost instances of programmers here on StackOverflow asking how to use regex to parse an XML entity or tag.
My question is: If we were to shift some parsing responsibility from regex onto parser, then what and to what extent features of modern regex (take PCRE for example) would remain sufficient for majority of the idiomatic/correct/normal/non-irregular use of regicies?

Back-reference would sure be redundent, as very few language require 2 identical tokens side-by-side.

This question is biased in a sense, that you assume regex is used solely paired with parser. However it is not mandatory, regex can be used purely for searching for example and then back reference comes handy.

What is the specific problem you are trying to solve here?

Many languages have proper parsers available, either directly or as well-supported libraries. So far this hasn’t reduced the idiomatic/correct/normal/non-irregular usecases of regex.

@whatsisname To identify the most useful subset of regex features for non-parsing uses. Admittedly subjective, can it be answered based on real-world use and mis-use, as well as hassles associated with regices?

I've rephrased my question. If no one finds interest in the present one, please close and delete it.

There is a strong theoretical relationship between backtracking-based regex engines with recursion like PCRE, LL(*) parsers, and PEG grammars. This doesn't mean regex engines have become too powerful, it means regexes are more useful than pure regular expressions, at acceptable performance. If you want more minimal regexes, look at the features available in automata-based regex engines like RE2. Notably: no backrefs, no lookarounds, no recursion.

Regular expressions is actually perfectly fine for recognizing xml tags or entities. In general regexes are a good tool for lexing or tokenization of a language. But regexes cannot be used to match start tags to end tags, since it cannot on its own handle recursive grammars. You need to combine regexes with a stack to parse arbitrary nested syntax.
